# How do I chat with someone in the chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat

How do I chat with someone in the chat rooms?

Comment: You need 20 rep points to write in Chat.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the entry [Talk in Chat](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) in the Help Center.

As @Flaw mentioned, you need 20 reputation points to participate in the conversation. You can always listen/watch.